# Count child nodes on XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Is there a way to count child nodes on an XDocument?

I looked for a count method or property and could not find one.

Thanks
Leo

Comment: I found a way using xdocument.Root.Nodes().Count(), but I am not sure if this is the best way to do. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify. An XDocument is the document that contains the XML data. Do you want to know the total number of rows in the document? Or do you want to know the child nodes of the root element of the document?

Comment: Daniel, thanks for you reply. This is what I was looking for.
doc.Descendants().Count();
Thanks Thomas.

Comment: Then you should set Thomas' response as answer.

Comment: GFK, I tried, but I guess there is a 10 minutes wait time before the set answer is active.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
int descendantsCount = doc.Descendants().Count(); // counts ALL descendants elements
int childrenCount = doc.Root.Elements().Count(); // counts direct children of the root element
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively ... if you know that the name of the elements are never going to change and they always exist,

```
XDocument xD = XDocument.Load(XmlFullFileName);
XElement xE_ParameterSets = xD.Root.Element("Report").Element("ParameterSets");
int index = ((IEnumerable<XElement>)xE_ParameterSets.Elements()).Count();
```